# Custom Libraries in code igniter and config files?

Tags: php, codeigniter, configuration-files, libraries

I have a library in code igniter that looks like `class MyClass($options = array())`

The file is `Myclass.php`

I have a file (`config/Myclass.php`) that looks like

```
$Myclass = array(
  'something' => 'value',
  'another'   => 'value'
);
```

Which I thought should pass the `$Myclass` array in when I initialize my class, but apparently not?

What do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AH I found the answer,

The array inside your config file **must** be called `$config`.

The name of the file must also be a *lower case* representation of the library file name.

e.g

LIB FILE:     `Somelibrary.php`
LIB CONTENTS: `class Somelibrary($options = array()){...`
CONF FILE:    `somelibrary.php`
CONF CONTENTS: `$config = array('something' => 'value');`

Answer (score 1):

The way this usually works is that you pass in an array of options you wish to override, or pass in nothing to use the defaults.

```
var myObject = new MyClass(); // default settings

var myObject = new MyClass(array('something' => 'value2')); // override only "something"
```

Honestly, I wouldn't create your own file in config without a good reason; instead, just put the defaults in your class definition, and then override in your constructor:

```
class MyClass {

    var $default_options = array(
        'something' => 'value',
        'another' => 'value',
    );
    var $options = array();

    function MyClass($override_options = array())
    {
        $this->options = array_merge($this->default_options, $override_options);

        // your code here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Luke,

I am aware it is not the best option to create a config file for your libraries all the time, but when your library has 30x options that can be set, then it is practical ;)

Answer (score 0):

Fast-forward to 2013, someone is still having problems with this.  So my situation was the same but slightly different,  so I thought I'd try to save someone else some time.

1. I was naming my config file after my extended class,  that was wrong.  **The Config file should always be form_validation.php**,  (this is because eventually it is handed to the CI_Form_validation class and that's what it expects)
2. Thanks to the folks who answered this question above, I realized that I had to pass the config to the parent class and using codeigniter v2.1.3 I did it as follows:

   ```
   public function __construct( $config = array() )
   {
     parent::__construct($config);
   }
   ```

Comment: Where did you come up with that CI version number? :-p

Comment: oops!.  I meant v2.1.3.  I was looking at my REST_Controller.php version.   I corrected it,  thanks.